# jQuery - Get Tallest Column in Row

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page that uses Bootstrap. I am trying to find the height of the largest column within each row. In an attempt to do this, I have:

**html:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <br />
    One
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Two
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <br />
    Three
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <br />
    One
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <br />
    <br />
    Two
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Three
  </div>
</div>
```

**javascript:**

```
$(function () {
  var rows = $('.row');
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var maxHeight = 0;

    var cols = null;  // NOT SURE WHAT TO DO TO GET THE COLUMNS HERE
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < cols.length; i2++) {
      var colHeight = $(cols[i2]).height();     // NOT SURE IF THIS IS CORRECT
      if (colHeight > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = colHeight;
      }
    }

    alert('Largest Column Height: ' + maxHeight);
  }
});
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/caca0chj/)

I'm not sure how to get all of the columns within a given row. At that point, I'm not entirely sure how to get the height. These are both rooted in the same problem: I don't understand when to use a selector and when not to.

How do I get all of the columns in a row and their respective heights?

Comment: you could use `cols = $(rows[i]).children('div[class^=col]');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the columns you need to use:

```
var cols = $(rows[i]).children('div');
```

The trick is that you always need to make the variable inside the **for** a jquery variable with **$(variable)** then you search for the children div.

The full code is:

```
$(function () {
  var rows = $('.row');
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

    var maxHeight = 0;

    var cols = $(rows[i]).children('div');  // NOT SURE WHAT TO DO TO GET THE COLUMNS HERE
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < cols.length; i2++) {
      var colHeight = $(cols[i2]).height();     // NOT SURE IF THIS IS CORRECT
      if (colHeight > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = colHeight;
      }
    }

    alert('Largest Column Height: ' + maxHeight);
  }
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/children/